# What advantage does a package-lock.json file have over specifying exact versions in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg, package-managers

Why not specify the exact version of dependencies you need in your package.json file, and forgo a lock file?  Why specify version wildcards/ranges in your package.json, if a lock file specifying exact versions is so desirable?

I must be missing something, because so many package managers have adopted the concept of a lock file.

What am I missing?